# I have 2,000,000 points in 100 dimensionality space. How can I cluster them to K (e.g., 1000) clusters?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

The problem comes as follows. I have M images and extract N features for each image, and the dimensionality of each feature is L. Thus, I have M*N features (2,000,000 for my case) and each feature has L dimensionality (100 for my case). I need to cluster these M*N features into K clusters. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want 1000 clusters of images, or of features, or of (image, feature) pairs ?
In any case, it sounds as though you'll have to reduce the data
and use simpler methods.

One possibility is two-pass K-cluster:
a) split the 2 million data points into 32 clusters,
b) split each of these into 32 more.
If this works, the resulting 32^2 = 1024 clusters might be good enough for your purpose.

Then, do you really need 100 coordinates ?
Could you guess the 20 most important ones,
or just try random subsets of 20 ?

There's a huge literature:  Google `+image "dimension reduction"` gives ~ 70000 hits.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I just did it as you suggested by two-pass K-cluster. The performance is very good.

Comment: Good; about how long did it run ?  (And how about clicking "accept" ?)

Comment: Can someone provide some kind of a documentation or reading material, for two-pass K-cluster? I'm not getting exactly what I need

Comment: @Mansi, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering describes the basic iteration, which you can also multilevel as in my old answer. What have you tried ? Can you describe the problem: about how many points, in what dimension, what K, images ? Do you have a [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged the question "k-means". Why can't you use k-means? Is this a question of efficiency?  (personally I've only used k-means in 2 dimensions) Or is it a question of how to encode the k-means algorithm?

Are your values discrete (eg. categories) or continuous (eg. a coordinate value)? If the latter, then k-means should be fine in my understanding. For the clustering of discrete values then a different algorithm will be required - perhaps hierarchical clustering?

Comment: Thanks for winwaed. 
It is often out of memory if I used "k-means". It is even not possible for me to load the data to memory (the features in text file is about 1.5G). My PC is with 2G RAM. I used matlab for this task. When I load 37.5% feature data, matlab told me out of memory.

Comment: So it is a size/efficiency issue. Is it possible to partition your data into three or four partitions which can processed in separate chunks?

Comment: Yes, it is a choice to partition the data into more partitions. I divided them into 20 partitions because the distance matrix would cost a lot of memory. Another problem is that how to combine the clusters of these 20 partitions effectively? It is also not clear  how much this partition method would effect the performance of clustering.

Answer (score 0):

The EM-tree and K-tree algorithms in the [LMW-tree](https://github.com/cmdevries/LMW-tree) project can cluster problems this big and larger. Our most recent result is clustering 733 million web pages into 600,000 clusters. There is also a streaming variant of the EM-tree where the dataset is streamed from disk for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A good trick when clustering millions of points is to sample them, cluster the sample, and then add the remaining points to the existing sample