# Clustering on a large dataset

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, large-data

I'm trying to cluster a large (Gigabyte) dataset.  In order to cluster, you need distance of every point to every other point, so you end up with a N^2 sized distance matrix, which in case of my dataset would be on the order of exabytes.  Pdist in Matlab blows up instantly of course ;)

Is there a way to cluster subsets of the large data first, and then maybe do some merging of similar clusters?

I don't know if this helps any, but the data are fixed length binary strings, so I'm calculating their distances using Hamming distance (Distance=string1 XOR string2).

Comment: How long are your bit strings ?

Comment: 128bits, 160bits, 256bits... they're cryptographic hashes.  I was trying to set it up generically enough that I can do it for different ones.  Are there any length dependent tricks?

Comment: I have a similar question several months ago.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153981/i-have-2-000-000-points-in-100-dimensionality-space-how-can-i-cluster-them-to-k
I wonder if the solution is workable for you?

Comment: @Jie, I went in a completely different direction with my experiment, but I'll give it a try, thanks for the idea.

Comment: not all clustering algorithms require ALL n^2 distances to be computed. For example, spectral clustering methods builds upon the transitivity property of similarity relations to allow for clustering using very SPARSE distances/affinity matrix (only a very small fraction of all n^2 distances is actually computed). If this approach sounds applicable for your case as well I'd be happy to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of the nice method from
Tabei et al., [Single versus Multiple Sorting in All Pairs Similarity Search](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v13/tabei10a/tabei10a.pdf),
say for pairs with Hammingdist 1:

- sort all the bit strings on the first 32 bits
- look at blocks of strings where the first 32 bits are all the same;
  these blocks will be relatively small
- pdist each of these blocks for Hammingdist( left 32 ) 0 + Hammingdist( the rest ) <= 1.

This misses the fraction of e.g. 32/128 of the nearby pairs which have
Hammingdist( left 32 ) 1 + Hammingdist( the rest ) 0.
If you really want these, repeat the above with "first 32" -> "last 32".

The method can be extended.
Take for example Hammingdist <= 2 on 4 32-bit words; the mismatches must split like one of
2000 0200 0020 0002 1100 1010 1001 0110 0101 0011,
so 2 of the words must be 0, sort the same.

(Btw, sketchsort-0.0.7.tar is 99 % src/boost/, build/, .svn/ .)

Comment: This sounds like it has potential, I'll try it and report back, thank you.

Comment: Marcin, let me know. For a bounty I could cobble together C++ that does fast std::sort on given wordnos, but have no idea how to connect such to Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting them first? Maybe something like a modified merge sort? You could start with chunks of the dataset which will fit in memory to perform a normal sort.

Once you have the sorted data, clustering could be done iteratively. Maybe keep a rolling centroid of N-1 points and compare against the Nth point being read in. Then depending on your cluster distance threshold, you could pool it into the current cluster or start a new one.

Comment: I've tried sorting, and it works great, but it only works on the patterns that start at the first bit.  If you have a pattern that starts somewhere in the middle and has random bits up front, then sort is not helpful at all.  That's why I'd rather go by Hamming distance.  I am thinking of dividing the strings into 4 different chunks, and sorting on them, but then you have a problem of patterns starting not exactly on the chunk boundry, so you're not catching all the patterns you could.

Comment: That bit of info in the question would help :). Couldnt you sort them based on Hamming distance rather then lexical?

Comment: I could, but to do that I would first have to create a huge matrix of Hamming distances, which is the exact thing I've been trying to avoid.

Comment: How about bin-sorting based on distance from an arbitrary point?

Answer (score 0):

The EM-tree and K-tree algorithms in the [LMW-tree](https://github.com/cmdevries/LMW-tree) project can cluster problems this big and larger. Our most recent result is clustering 733 million web pages into 600,000 clusters. There is also a streaming variant of the EM-tree where the dataset is streamed from disk for each iteration.

Additionally, these algorithms can cluster bit strings directly where all cluster representatives and data points are bit strings, and the similarity measure that is used is Hamming distance. This minimizes the Hamming distance within each cluster found.